# Copy data from local disk to HDFS in a federation of HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, federation, webhdfs

1. I use two hosts (hadoop-coc-1 and hadoop-coc-2) to try to configure a Federation of HDFS in them. Therefore, I configured the `$ cat etc/hadoop/hdfs-site.xml` in both hosts (hadoop-coc-1, and hadoop-coc-2).

Both HDFS are running properly with the WebHDFS. But, with this configuration, the defaultFS service is not running. Maybe this is a reason that I can't copy data from local disk to HDFS.

I have tried to copy data with the following commands:

```
$ hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ~/input1 webhdfs://hadoop-coc-1/
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM warning: You have loaded library /home/xubuntu/Programs/hadoop-2.6.0/lib/native/libhadoop.so which might  have disabled stack guard. The VM will try to fix the stack guard now.
It's highly recommended that you fix the library with 'execstack -c <libfile>', or link it with '-z noexecstack'.
15/03/02 12:32:47 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
copyFromLocal: Connection refused


$ curl -i -X PUT -T ~/input1 "http://hadoop-coc-1:8080/?op=CREATE"
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 405 HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 17:34:35 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Date: Mon, 02 Mar 2015 17:34:35 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Length: 0
Server: Jetty(6.1.26)
```

I don't understand why I can't copy data from local disk to HDFS that is using WebHDfS protocol. Any help to understand this error? Why I can't copy data from the local disk to HDFS? Did I configure well the hdfs-site.xml?

hdfs-site.xml in hadoop-coc-1 and hadoop-coc-2 hosts.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.nameservices</name>
     <value>ns1,ns2</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS.ns1</name>
     <value>hdfs://hadoop-coc-1:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>fs.defaultFS.ns2</name>
     <value>hdfs://hadoop-coc-2:9000</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ns1</name>
     <value>hadoop-coc-1:6600</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ns1</name>
     <value>hadoop-coc-1:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.secondaryhttp-address.ns1</name>
     <value>hadoop-coc-1:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.rpc-address.ns2</name>
     <value>hadoop-coc-2:6600</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.http-address.ns2</name>
     <value>hadoop-coc-2:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.namenode.secondaryhttp-address.ns2</name>
     <value>hadoop-coc-2:8080</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.webhdfs.enabled</name>
     <value>true</value>
    </property>
    <property>
     <name>dfs.support.append</name>
     <value>true</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

2. Federation of HDFS allows to have several namespaces to access HDFS. With my configuration (see hdfs-site.xml), hadoop-coc-1 and hadoop-coc-2 host have a namespace to the same HDFS. I wonder if it is possible to have two YARN runtimes running in each host that uses the same HDFS?

Answer (score 1):

The default web server port is 50070 and the data is streamed from datanodes by webservers on port **50075**. Had you changed this configuration somewhere?

Furthermore, when you try to copy data to the webdfs you specify no port

http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/webhdfs.html